# Reset form fields after form submission in wordpress custom contact form plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've my own custom contact form wordpress plugin, in which I'm unable to reset the form fields after the user submits the form.

When the user fills up all the fields and submits, success message will be shown, and after that I need the form to reset all the fields. At present it shows the values entered by the user before submission.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Contact Form
Plugin URI: 
Description: <code>[contact email="your@email.address"]</code>
Version: 1.0
Author: 
Author URI: 
*/

// function to get the IP address of the user
function tw_get_the_ip() {
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {
    return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
}
else {
    return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
}

// the shortcode
function tw_contact_form_sc($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "email" => get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
    "subject" => '',
    "label_name" => 'Your Name',
    "label_email" => 'Your E-mail Address',
    "label_subject" => 'Subject',
    "label_message" => 'Your Message',
    "label_submit" => 'Submit',
    "error_empty" => 'Please fill in all the required fields.',
    "error_noemail" => 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.',
    "success" => 'Thanks for your e-mail! We\'ll get back to you as soon as we can.'
), $atts));

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $error = false;
    $required_fields = array("your_name", "email", "message", "subject");

    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $form_data[$field] = strip_tags($value);
    }

    foreach ($required_fields as $required_field) {
        $value = trim($form_data[$required_field]);
        if(empty($value)) {
            $error = true;
            $result = $error_empty;
        }
    }

    if(!is_email($form_data['email'])) {
        $error = true;
        $result = $error_noemail;
    }

    if ($error == false) {
        $email_subject = "[" . get_bloginfo('name') . "] " . $form_data['subject'];
        $email_message = $form_data['message'] . "\n\nIP: " . tw_get_the_ip();
        $headers  = "From: ".$form_data['your_name']." <".$form_data['email'].">\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
        wp_mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
        $result = $success;
        $sent = true;
    }
}

if($result != "") {
    $info = '<div class="info">'.$result.'</div>';
}
$email_form = '<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="'.get_permalink().'">
    <div>
        <label for="cf_name">'.$label_name.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="your_name" id="cf_name" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$form_data['your_name'].'" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cf_email">'.$label_email.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="cf_email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$form_data['email'].'" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cf_subject">'.$label_subject.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="cf_subject" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$subject.$form_data['subject'].'" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cf_message">'.$label_message.':</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="cf_message" cols="50" rows="15">'.$form_data['message'].'</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="'.$label_submit.'" name="send" id="cf_send" />
    </div>
</form>';

if($sent == true) {
        return $info.$email_form;
} else {
        return $info.$email_form;
}
} add_shortcode('contact', 'tw_contact_form_sc');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance you can just manually assign your values on `$sent == true`:

```
// Presumably if the email is sent, you want blank values instead
// of populated ones.
if($sent == true) {
        $form_data['your_name'] =   "";
        $form_data['email']     =   "";
        $form_data['subject']   =   "";
        $form_data['message']   =   "";
    }

$email_form = '<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="'.get_permalink().'">
    <div>
        <label for="cf_name">'.$label_name.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="your_name" id="cf_name" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$form_data['your_name'].'" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cf_email">'.$label_email.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="cf_email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$form_data['email'].'" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cf_subject">'.$label_subject.':</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="cf_subject" size="50" maxlength="50" value="'.$subject.$form_data['subject'].'" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="cf_message">'.$label_message.':</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="cf_message" cols="50" rows="15">'.$form_data['message'].'</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="'.$label_submit.'" name="send" id="cf_send" />
    </div>
</form>';
```

There are lots of ways to do this, but without doing much in the way of modifying what you have, this is probably the quickest.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ajax/Json for submit form, then after submit form put a simple code in ajax/json

```
$('form').reset();
```

also you set a custom class for all input fields just ex. class name :clear
then use

```
$('.class').val('');
```

and simple answer is this:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
```